# Problem with Finding Likelihood: Bayesian

Tags: probability, bayesian, likelihood, bayes

I am really unfamiliar with Bayesian methods particularly parameter estimation.

Suppose I have a test to find a parameter, theta which is the number of packaged bag for retail sale that could contain a hidden toy. I consider the following values of theta to be possible: `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`. I am interested in the following two hypotheses:

```
H0: theta == (no toys) 
H1: theta =/= 0 (there are toys in a bag)
```

To test these hypotheses, I theoretically perform an experiment. Instead of testing all five of the bags (avoid damaging the packaging), I pick one of the bags at random and test for a toy. Using a testing machine, it is designed to say 1 if there are toys found and 0 if no toys were found. When a bag was tested, the result (the data) was:

```
x1 = 0
```

That is, no toys were found in the first bag that was tested.

I've used parameter estimation theory using prior distributions. But I am struggling with finding the likelihood. Am I supposed to do a Beta distribution to do so? Or binomial, in which there is 0 successes in 1 trial for theta?

Comment: So you have six bags, each of which may contain a single toy, and you want to know the probability distribution of the total number of toys after looking in just one of the bags?

Comment: I guess so? I don't know if I'm overthinking with using all these functions or I'm just supposed to use common sense.

Comment: Use common sense, i.e. make an informed modeling choice. Bayesian statistics requires that you pick a likelihood and to pick a likelihood you need some familiarity with a few common probability distributions. You are probably looking for the binomial, but it could be the negative binomial, geometric, Bernoulli, or even Poisson. I don't know which one because you haven't framed your question very well.

Comment: I recommend keeping on reading and digging around until you can structure your problem using the Bayes' Theorem, conceptually. If you posted the question in that form, it is a lot more likely that you will get an answer. And in the process you will have become more familiar with bayesian methods. win/win!

Comment: Some useful advices on this topic can be found in: NordgaardA. (2006) Quantifying experience in sample size determination for drug analysis of seized drugs. Law, Probability and Risk 4: 217-225 <http://lpr.oxfordjournals.org/content/4/4/217.full.pdf+html>